# Custom fonts in `rmarkdown`/`bookdown`: Retaining **bold**/*italic*, special font features (`--`) etc.?

Tags: fonts, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

After installing `D-Din` as `*.otf` from [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/d-din) (`fc-list` shows it and the exact naming is used below), I have added the following to my `rmarkdown`/`bookdown` header:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
  ...
  latex_engine: lualatex
...
mainfont: D-DIN:style=Regular
sansfont: D-DIN:style=Regular
```

This compiles nicely and the font gets used **but** I use all formatting like bold and italic, as well as glyph-magic like `--` to `en`-dash etc. Not surprising, maybe, as I explicitly ask for the `Regular` version ... Can anyone point out how I may instruct `tinytex`/`lualatex`/`pandoc` to make use of the full weight etc. spectrum for `D-Din` available on the system?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the spelling mistake.

Comment: maybe you need to ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com... note also that lualatex, xelatex and the default pdflatex (of which tinytex is a subset AFAIK) each have very different font handlings... see also https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf for the basics